# MAUI BringIntoView() the ContentView like in WPF

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

For a control in WPF there is a `BringIntoView()` function which automatically will scroll the parent to be able to see the entire control.
Is there something simmilar for a ContentView in MAUI?

**Edit:**

Based on comment of @FreakyAli , if there is not such an event, how could this be done? How can I automatically scroll the `ScrollView` which contains an `ExtendedFlexLayout` control, with a custom view set as `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`?
My `ScrollView` looks like this:

```cs
<ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" >
    <controls:ExtendedFlexLayout
        AlignItems="Start"
        Direction="Row"
        Wrap="Wrap"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PacksList}">
        <controls:ExtendedFlexLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:PackView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:ExtendedFlexLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:ExtendedFlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`ExtendedFlexLayout` is a custom FlexLayout control.

Comment: I doubt there is something like that in MAUI or XF

Comment: You could use `ScrollView.ScrollToAsync()` like proposed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455048/programmatically-scroll-at-scrollview-without-animation#42459058, but you'll have to figure out the coordinates of your element inside the FlexLayout by yourself.

Comment: I found the solution to this problem, and I've enhance it, that I could scroll programatically the ScrollView control as the child of the FlexLayout to be aligned at the top, at the bottom, center or nearest :) This is awesome!

Comment: After I worked some time on this, I found that `ScrollToAsync()` has two constructors and the second constructor makes what I need :)) ohhhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ewerspej comment, I found that `ScrollToAsync()` event has two constructors. Both constructor accept three arguments, the third one is for animating scroll process for both constructors.

The first constructor allows you to `Scroll a position into view` and it passes two values of `double` type, one for the `x` (horizontal) and one for the `y` (vertical).

```cs
await scrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, 150, true);
```

The second constructor is for `Scroll an element into view`, which accept a visual element as the first argument, the second argument is `ScrollToPosition` enum, which offers four options: `MakeVisible`, `Start`, `Center` and `End`.

The following example will bring into view the label, and will align it to the bottom of `scrollView` control:

```cs
await scrollView.ScrollToAsync(label, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

The link to Microsoft MAUI `ScrollView` page is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview) .